# Spring redirecting to a part of the URL

Tags: spring, security, redirect, logout

Using Spring boot, the logout is setup this way:

```
 @Override
 protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

    http
      .logout()
      .logoutSuccessUrl("https://www.my-sso-server.com/logout?
           redirectto=https://www.my-appli-server.com/my-context")
    ;
```

But in the server response, the redirection URL is 
https://www.my-appli-server.com/my-context

I double checked everything in debug mode and noticed that changing the context, the redirection url is the full one: eg.

```
https://www.my-sso-server.com/logout?redirectto=https://www.my-appli-server.com/not-my-context
```

is well redirected to this url

It seems that having the current context in a parameter's url will redirect to this same url.

Is there any explanation to this behaviour? How to by-pass it?

Note: I also tried to define a custom LogoutSuccessHandler in which I process manually to the redirection with:

```
response.setStatus(HttpServletResponse.SC_FOUND);
response.setHeader("Location", ...
```

but the result is the same

Answer (score 0):

In your developer tools turn on `preserve log`. Your browser merges all redirects into (first request, last response).

[image]

Comment: yes, you might be correct and +1 means, thumbs up :)